# Unknown TCP protocol - Trying to send data to device

Tags: macos, tcp, terminal

I'm trying to communicate with a network device over TCP and I am not sure where to start. The device has an application for PC and iPhone/Android but I want to extend the functionality. The developer sent me a document with some directions to send commands and data over TCP but I am not sure where to start.

The documentation is sparse and was written from a non-english native country (China). It says:

**Data protocol format for TCP communications:**

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Command Head | 0x7E | 1 byte |
| Data Length | >=0 | Int (4byte) |
| Command Type | 0x01~0xFF (Each command is different) | 1 byte |
| Data | String | >= 0 |
| Command Tail | 0x7F | 1 byte |

It then gives examples of how to communicate with the device:

**Example 1**

Command sent: `0x01`

Description: PC send request device information send data: `null,DataLength=0`

Returns command: `0x02`

Return description: the device returns the device information

Return Data:the example is as follows,

`Data=" DeviceIdData=10001000111& DisplayImageIdData=abc.mp4&SecondData=0& StatusCodeData=1&Version=100&HardVersion=100&DeviceMacAdd=feac80808080&Adve rtiseCode=0& Power=1&DeviceName=Z3H" DataLength=strlen(Data)`

**Example 2**
Send command: `0x0f`

Send description: Brightness adjustment (0-255, 0 is the darkest, 255 is the brightest), when the data is null to obtain the brightness value

Send data: the following adjust the brightness to 50,

```
Data=”Luminance=50”
DataLength=strlen(Data)
Data=”save”
DataLength=strlen(Data)
```

In order to save the current data, the next time turn on the device to keep this brightness. no “Save” command will not be recorded.
Return command: 16

Return description: Return the current or the brightness value that was set

Return data:

```
Data=“luminance=50”
DataLength=strlen(Data)
```

---

I found [this application](https://packetsender.com/) that I can use to send commands to the device and see a response, but I cannot figure out how to send and receive the data strings. I'm a software engineer but I mainly do JavaScript web applications and some Ruby, but this is something I have no idea how to tackle.

Super grateful for any help

Comment: You could start by telling us what operating system and programming language you plan to use, but really this is far too broad. There are plenty of network programming tutorials out there, and some of them are even correct.

Comment: Thanks! For now, I’m just building a POC. So, if there was a node.js framework that would be great, as I am proficient in JavaScript. I am on macOS on a MacBook Pro.